# How to get instance of RemoteWebDriver Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium-grid

```
public RemoteWebDriver driver;

public void Login() throws Exception {
    if (driver instanceof ChromeDriver || driver instanceof FirefoxDriver) {
        driver.get(URL);
    } else if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
        driver.get(URL2);
        enterCred();
    } else if (driver instanceof OperaDriver) {
        driver.get(URL2);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the instance of the RemoteWebDriver but the code above doesn't seem to work. I have to get a 2 separate URLs because of how internet explorer handles the login procedure. The code above worked when I was using just a normal webdriver but now that it is a RemoteWebDriver, IE is not being able to get the proper URL.

It will work if I take out everything from login to `driver.get(URL);` but only for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: think i figured it out. i get do driver.toString(); and it will get something like this.                                                                                                             [**RemoteWebDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (6101278d-fc76-4459-9545-cf0e0052e30b)**]

Comment: You should post this as an answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think i figured it out. i get do driver.toString(); and it will get something like this. [RemoteWebDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (6101278d-fc76-4459-9545-cf0e0052e30b)].

After i got that i just looked for the keyword "firefox", "chrome", or "internet explorer"